# Why is my computer booting into emergency mode after changing fstab?

Tags: boot, 18.04, mount, fstab

I have an external USB hard drive that I configured to automatically mount to a specific location when it is connected. I configured this by:
adding the following line in `/etc/crypttab`:

```
device_name UUID=device-uuid-abcd-1234 none luks
```

... and adding the following line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/device_name /home/myuser/desired-directory/ ext4 user 0 0
```

And it was working perfectly!

Whenever I connected the external hard drive, I would be prompted for its encryption password, and after entering the correct password I could find all its data in my configured directory.

The trouble is... when I reboot my laptop, I am booted into emergency mode (presumably only when the external drive is not attached). And no matter what command I issue... I cannot boot in into Ubuntu normally.

If I comment out the line I added to `fstab`, I can boot normally (I do **not** have to comment out the line I added in `crypttab`).

What do I need to do so that my computer boots normally and automatically mounts my hard drive whenever it is plugged in?

Comment: Is the luks device opened / decrypted when booting without the fstab entry? Initial guess: try noauto &/or nofail in the fstab 4th field

Comment: @Xen2050 Hey, thanks for the tips, but those don't give me the desired behavior. :( Yes, I can manually open/decrypt without the entries in fstab and crypttab. I edited my post to make it more clear what the problem is and what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Xen2050 Wow, I have an apology to make. You are right, adding the noauto option makes it work. I swear I tried it before, but it did not mount when plugged in... but I must have had something else misconfigured. Anyways, I added the option now, and everything works just as I want it to. the external drive is mounted when plugged in, and my laptop boots normally when it is not. If you want to add your suggestion as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you!